# Ayuda con obtener el id de un formulario PHP / MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tengo un problema para obtener el id de un formulario:

Tengo en mi base de datos una tabla llamada asistencias el cual quiero editar una observación por formulario cada vez que quiera.

en mi lista tengo:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <body>
<?php 
  include 'conexion.php';

  $datos_asistencia = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM asistencias");
  //$datos_trabajador = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM empleados");//


?>

<!--parte central de asistencias donde se imprimen los empleados a los cuales se les puede agregar una asistencia solo los activos-->
<small><h3>Lista de asistencia (completas)</h3></small>
<hr>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Fecha</th>
    <th>Hora Entrada</th>
    <th>Hora Salida</th>
    <th>Observación</th>
    <th>Añadir</th>
  </thead>
  <?php while ($asistencias = mysqli_fetch_array($datos_asistencia)) { ?>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $asistencias["id"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $asistencias["fecha"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $asistencias["horaEntrada"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $asistencias["horaSalida"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $asistencias["observacion"]; ?></td>
      <td><a href="crear-observacion.php?id=<?php echo $asistencias["id"]; ?>">Añadir</a></td>
    </tr>

     <?php  } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

en asistencias tengo:

```
asistencias (id, fecha, horaEntrada, horaSalida, observacion, empleado_id)
```

Y quiero editar observación.

Tengo mi formulario donde "supuestamente obtengo el id":

```
<form method="post" action="guardar-observacion.php">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $asistencia["id"]; ?>">
<textarea name="observacion" value="<?php echo $asistencia['observacion']; ?
>" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea> <br>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
</form>
```

y en mi guardar-observacion.php tengo:

```
<?php 
//UPDATE `asistencias` SET `observacion`= "Hola Mundo" WHERE `id` = 17//
include 'conexion.php';

$observacion = $_POST["observacion"];

$agregar = "UPDATE `asistencias` SET `observacion`= '$observacion' WHERE 
`id` = '{$_GET["id"]}' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $agregar);
?>
```

Ahora lo que necesito es tomar y que edite el id seleccionado del formulario, y lo guarde ya actualizado.

Comment: Acaso en tu formulario no tiene que ser así:
 `<input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $asistencias['id']; ?>">`

Comment: Además de que al input hieren le falta el nombre, si envías el formulario por post no puedes recoger id por get y viceversa, usa $_REQUEST

Answer (score 2):

Añade nombre al input hidden:

```
<form method="post" action="guardar-observacion.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $asistencia["id"]; ?>">
    <textarea name="observacion" value="<?php echo $asistencia['observacion']; ?
    >" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea> <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
    </form>
```

Y en guardar-observacion.php recoge las variables por post o request:

```
 <?php 
    ....

    $agregar = "UPDATE `asistencias` SET `observacion`= '$observacion' WHERE 
    `id` = '{$_POST["id"]}' ";
    ....
    ?>
```

Comment: Me sale: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project93\guardar-observacion.php on line 22

Comment: Eso indicaría que el input name= "id" no está definido en el formulario, si te pones encima del formulario en el navegador y le das a inspeccionar con el botón derecho ves el input hidden con name y con el valor que debe tener? Por cierto, el botón hace un submit del formulario por post, no?

Comment: el id debe tomar el valor de id en asistencia

Comment: Si, y en el navegador puedes comprobar que está correcto porque verías los valores que se van a enviar

Comment: Escribir consultas como esta: `$agregar = "UPDATE asistencias SET observacion= '$observacion' WHERE 
    id = '{$_POST["id"]}' ";` es una **pésima práctica de programación**. ¿El motivo? **Inyección SQL**. Imaginemos que en el input `id` alguien escribe esto: **`17; DROP TABLE asistencias; DROP TABLE otra-tabla, DROP TABLE ooootra-tabla`** Así, te conviertes en tu propio hacker, dejando la puerta abierta para que te borren todas tus tablas, u otras cosas peores. Luego te vas a quejar, pero no hay otro culpable que tú por escribir código vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado: El problema estaba en la consulta.

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$observacion = $_POST["observacion"];
$agregar = "UPDATE `asistencias` SET `observacion`= '$observacion' WHERE 
`id` = '$id' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $agregar);
```